# Last line ignored using ANTLR for C#

Tags: c#, antlr

We use C# version 4.6.4 of ANTLR to parse code snippets used in our tools. The grammar is similar to IEC61131, the Pascal-like PLC language. When someone enters a snippet and forgets the semicolon ending the last line, this line is just ignored by the parser. What can I do to get some feedback on this? I need to at least give an error message to the user.

I already have an error handler:

```
class ErrorListener : IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>
{
    public void SyntaxError(IRecognizer recognizer, IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        _errorLine = offendingSymbol.Line;
        _errorColumn = offendingSymbol.Column + 1;
        _errorText = "Error on line " + _errorLine + ", column " + _errorColumn;
    }
}
```

My lexer and parser functions are:

```
public CommonTokenStream Lex(string stLike)
{
    AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream(stLike);
    IEC61131Lexer lexer = new IEC61131Lexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

    return tokenStream;
}

public IParseTree Parse(CommonTokenStream tokenStream)
{
    IEC61131Parser parser = new IEC61131Parser(tokenStream);
    ErrorListener listener = new ErrorListener();
    parser.AddErrorListener((IAntlrErrorListener<IToken>)listener);

    return parser.iec_source();
}
```

They are called like this:

```
    CommonTokenStream tokenStream = Lex(stLike);
    IParseTree tree = Parse(tokenStream);

    // If parsing went OK, _errorText will be empty
    if (_errorText == "")
    {
        // Walk the tree to create code
        IEC61131PlcVisitor visitor = new IEC61131PlcVisitor(theClass, tokenStream, target);
        visitor.Indent = indent;
        result = visitor.Visit(tree);
    }
    else
    {
        result = "<" + _errorText + ">";
    }
```

When I parse a code snippet with a missing semicolon at the end, the lexer generates tokens for it, but the parser stops at the last semicolon.

[image: Lexer contents]

[image: Parser debug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `EOF` token at the end of `iec_source` rule.

That way the parser will know it has to reach end of input and will emit an error if it does not find end of file after the last recognized statement.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! (And sorry for my slow response.)